# Google Sheets Apps Script get range of entire sheet even if it has no data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

Let's say I define a sheet `thissheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name)` where `name` is a string with the name of one of my sheets.

I know if I have data in the sheet, I can use `thissheet.getDataRange()` to select it all.
Or, alternately `thissheet.getRange(1,1,thissheet.getLastRow(),thissheet.getLastCol())`

But what if I want the whole sheet selected as a range regardless of whether it has data or not?

Or, in my particular instance, I have ran `thissheet.clear()` and cleared all the data in my sheet but I need to use `thissheet.somerange.removeCheckboxes()` where `somerange` basically represents the entire sheet as a `Range` object to clear all the empty checkboxes left behind because `clear()` doesn't clear the checkboxes.

OK, so first thing is I need to make sure I run `thissheet.dataRange().removeCheckboxes()` in my script sequence before `thissheet.clear()`. That works so long as I control everything and follow certain rules. This still leaves two problems:

1. Once I deploy my script and other users start using it, it would be fairly easy for someone to clear the sheet and leave the checkboxes behind and it will cause my script to crash later because `.dataRange()` will effectively be no range.
2. If I have checkboxes in the last row or last column with no other data, they still won't get cleared because they won't be part of `.dataRange()`

So how can I ensure all the checkboxes in my sheet have been removed?

Comment: Checkboxes have data whether they checked or unchecked.

Comment: ```thisSheet.getRange("K2:K).removeCheckboxes()``` where ```K``` can be replaced by the column containing your checkboxes - unless I've gotten it completely wrong.

Comment: if(Cell.getDataValidation().getCriteriaType() == "CHECKBOX") means Cell has a checkbox in it

Comment: If you select your entire sheet by clicking in the up left corner just above and left of A1 and then pick Data/Data Validation and click remove it will remove all data validations on the page

Comment: @santosOnit thanks for the suggestion, but in my case I don't necessarily know WHICH column they checkboxes will be in, they depend on outside data so that won't work.

Comment: @Cooper using getDataValidation() is an interesting angle, thanks for the suggestion. I find it a very interesting choice by Google that they tie the checkboxes to validation.  I think Tanaike has a simpler, more straight forward approach for me though. As for clicking the upper left box - yes, that works, but I needed a way to do it automatically in my script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Removing all checkboxes in a sheet.

In your situation, in order to retrieve all cells in a sheet, how about using `getMaxRows` and `getMaxColumns`? When this reflects in a script, it becomes as follows.

```js
const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
const range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns());

range.removeCheckboxes().clear(); // Here, the checkboxes and cells are cleared.
```

- If you want to remove only checkboxes, please modify `range.removeCheckboxes().clear()` to `range.removeCheckboxes()`.

#### 2. Checking checkboxes in a sheet.

In order to confirm whether all checkboxes are removed in a sheet, how about the following sample script?

```js
const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
const range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns());

const checkCheckboxes = range.getDataValidations().flatMap((r, i) => r.flatMap((c, j) => c && c.getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX ? {row: i + 1, col: j + 1} : []));
if (checkCheckboxes.length == 0) {

  console.log("No checkboxes in this sheet.");

} else {

  console.log("Checkboxes are existing in the cells.");
  console.log(checkCheckboxes); // Here, you can see the cell coordinates of the checkboxes.

}
```

#### Note:

- For example, I think that Sheets API can be also used in your situation. But I guessed that from your question, using Spreadsheet service might be suitable. So, I proposed the above answers.

#### References:

- [getMaxRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows)
- [getMaxColumns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxcolumns)
- [getDataValidations()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDataValidations())

Comment: Thank You. #1 is exactly what I was asking for. I was stuck on `.getLastRow()` and `.getLastColumn()` when I needed `.getMaxRow()` and `.getMaxColumn` - this ensures everything is selected regardless of contents and makes sure I can always completely clear my sheet of everything. For my future work doing more checking / verifying after I get my basic script working your #2 and Cooper's suggestions will help as well.

Answer (score 0):

For all intents and purposes, checkboxes  contain data, whether checked or not. This is also mentioned by [@Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71533737/google-sheets-apps-script-get-range-of-entire-sheet-even-if-it-has-no-data#comment126430924_71533737)

> Once I deploy my script and other users start using it, it would be fairly easy for someone to clear the sheet and leave the checkboxes behind and it will cause my script to crash later because .dataRange() will effectively be no range.

This is not the case as `.getDataRange()` will default to `A1` in case no data is found.

> If I have checkboxes in the last row or last column with no other data, they still won't get cleared because they won't be part of .dataRange()

Checkboxes are part of the datarange. When you add a checkbox, it contains `FALSE` by default.

Comment: you made some good points. I ran a test script with all scenarios - and `.getDataRange()` does default to `A1` so it doesn't crash my script. When I used `.getLastRow()` and `.getLastColumn()` it crashed my scripted because they returned 0. I assumed `.getDataRange()` would be similar. However, per my original question, if someone clears the sheet, the data is removed from the checkboxes but leaves the checkboxes behind, so `.getDataRange()` no longer selects them at that point. I fixed my script to prevent that in the script itself, but I can't prevent other users from doing it.

Comment: @Trashman `if someone clears the sheet, the data is removed from the checkboxes but leaves the checkboxes behind` During my testing, checkboxes are also removed.